# Installing expat XML Parser to utilize bluetooth in arm board

Tags: linux, bluetooth, arm, dbus, expat-parser

hi I am a beginner as programmer so ,in advance, appreciate for you patience to understand what I wrote. I'm trying to cross-compile the bluetooth libraries.
Device is an arm-processor board,

and my cross-compiler is arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc

I have succeeded to install zlib, libffi, GLib, and I think all I have done is changing the cross-compiler's name..(or change the directory)

so I have to cross-compile

1. expat-2.1.0.tar.gz
2. dbus-1.8.0.tar.gz
3. libical-1.0.tar.gz

however, when I tried to install expat XML parser by following

1. download expat-2.1.0.tar.gz
2. unzip and get into that directory to do
   ./configure --host=arm-none-linux-gnueabi --prefix=/usr/arm-none-linux-gnueabi
3. make
4. sudo make install 
   (here i ran into another prob, libtool couldn't run the arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ranlib.  I found the very directory manually added /opt/arm-2009q3/bin to the codes in libtool file)

so upto here everything seemed fine but when I tried to configure dbus-1.8.0.tar.gz(after unzip it as well) here comes trouble.

configure: WARNING: Cannot check for abstract sockets when cross-compiling, please use --enable-abstract-sockets
checking for XML_ParserCreate_MM in -lexpat... no
configure: error: Explicitly requested expat but expat not found

the very first line is cleared as soon as i followed the recommended direction
but I have no clue about new two problems.

I have tried on the lower version of expat(expat 2.0.1.tar.gz) and so on, but I couldn't solve it.. I admit I don't fully understand what I'm doing and just I'm just copy&pasting. So please be tolerant to help me resolve this question.. Thank you

p.s if anybody had the reference site for utilizing bluetooth in embedded linux, plz let me know!

Answer (score 0):

This error usually means the build is looking in the wrong place for pkgconfig and its libs (probably looking at the host pkgconfig rather than the cross compilation tree). Try configure with `PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR` and `PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR` set. The former should be set to where the cross compile build puts its `.pc` files and the latter should be set to the cross compile sysroot.